# How to declare closeCell() method for a particular row-item in Angular-JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid which is editable, but at a particular column of a row I want to make it stable(non-editable) if it meets certain requirements,

This is the code for my grid

```js
$scope.Grid = {
        dataSource : new kendo.data.DataSource({
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: 'Id',
                    fields: {
                        Id:{type:'number'},
                        Name: { type: "string" },
                        Description: { type: "string" },
                        Remarks: { type: "string" },
                        ApprovalStatus: { type: "string" }

                    }
                }
            }
        }),
        selectable: true,
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        scrollable: false,
        edit: edit,
        save: update,
```

These are my edit and update functions

```js
function edit(e) {
      
        e.model.Id = e.model.Id == "" ? 0 : e.model.Id;
      
        if(e.model.ApprovalStatus === 'Waiting')
        {
           $('#Grid').data("kendoGrid").closeCell();
        }
        
    }

    function update(e) {

        var Data = {
            Id: e.model.Id != "" && e.model.Id > 0 ? e.model.Id : 0,
            Name: e.model.Name,
            Description: e.model.Description,
            Remarks: e.model.Remarks,
            ApprovalStatus: e.model.ApprovalStatus
        }

        ciSetUp.setPayLoad({ Info: Data });
        ciSetUp.postdata(e.model.Id).then(function () {
            console.log(ciSetUp.postcreatedata);
        });


    }
```

So if ApprovalStatus is equal to Waiting, Approval Status field should become non-editable, which I'm not able to get.

It works fine till the if condition, but the thing inside the loop doesn't execute

Comment: What kind of editing are you doing? inline?

Comment: Check [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YXt9OnZIovsH7CCAUkiF?p=preview) and see what's different from your setup

Comment: Yeah, inline editing

Comment: It is not working because I'm doing this in Angular-JS. And this line  $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").closeCell(); this line is not working there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `$('#Grid').data("kendoGrid").closeCell();`, use `e.sender.closeCell();`

**EDIT:**
The above answer is for `incell` editing mode. When using `inline` editing mode, use `e.sender.cancelRow();` instead.

See [this Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YXt9OnZIovsH7CCAUkiF?p=preview).

Comment: There is still a problem, when I'm using incell editing like you did it is working fine, but if I use inline editing it is not allowing to edit anything still it gives the blinking cursor in the boxes, which is like a bug.

It also give an error when I click on the edit button "Unable to find template of undefined or null reference"

Comment: What problem exactly? The cell remains in edit mode?

Comment: It remains in edit mode, but not allowing to edit anything, 
which means it is working partially

Comment: I think, the thing to be disabled is k-grid-edit property which is giving chance to edit inline, but not accepting the edited changes

Comment: Yes, It is working perfect for incell edit. For inline, comes the problem

Comment: Oh that explains it - `closeCell` works only with `incell` editing mode, as written in the Kendo documentation.

Comment: Is it a problem making the editing `incell` instead of `inline`?

Comment: Yeah, I was asked to make it inline. So,I should fulfill their requirements

Comment: Oh ok, so what you're looking for is `cancelRow`. I've updated my demo.

Comment: Cool ! Working fine, I had a try on `closeRow()` previously but not this

Comment: Great, happy to have helped! If the answer suited you, please accept it :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44716489/how-to-use-postupdate-of-data-having-child-objects-in-them can you go through this question once